# copy selected text from textarea to clipboard using javascript or flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am completely new with javascript and html and have never written code in javascript before. I want to create a button that allows the user to copy the selected text in the textarea to the clipboard. I do not have a problem with using flash but I have never done it before so any help will much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hope this will help you. http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-copy-clipboard-4-options/

Answer (score 2):

for IE you can use

```
function copyData (str) {

    window.clipboardData.setData('Text',str); }
```

or try the following link
http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-using-jquery_501.html